# How to declare and use AJAX data in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

For example I have **AJAX script**:

```
$('#send_profile').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:UTF-8",
            global: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/user/change',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                name: $("#profile_name").val(),
                nickname: $("#profile_nickname").val(),
                surname: $("#profile_surname").val(),
                country: $("#profile_country").val(),
                city: $("#profile_city").val(),
                phone: $("#profile_phone").val(),
                age: $("#profile_age").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

And my **server code**, that should add data from ajax request to database.

```
router.post('/change', function (req, res) {
var nickname = req.body.nickname,
name = req.body.name,
surname = req.body.surname,
age = req.body.age,
country = req.body.country,
city = req.body.city,
phone = req.body.phone;

User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$set:{ nickname: nickname, name: name, surname: surname, age: age, country: country, city: city, phoneNumber: phone }}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }
    console.log(doc);
});
});
```

And have a message: 
Something wrong when updating data!
undefined

So I think my variables ain't correct, how to fix it? How can I declare my ajax data?

Comment: have you tried req.params

Comment: @Dherya console.log(req.params) shows me empty object "{}"...

Comment: @Dherya it's so big...https://jsfiddle.net/hus1u3e7/

Comment: Can you debug and see if the problem is the req.body is empty or maybe it is req.user

Comment: There is some missing data here. I'm assuming you are using express (is that correct?), but did you set any middleware function to parse the body?

Comment: @Shahar Bental Express, it's correct. I am using bodyParser. My code is working well without ajax...

Comment: @BimBam Can you share the require and use statements you use for the body parser? If the body is empty, then this is probably the reason